# Why can 'create table' in Postgres take several seconds?

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.4

In my project we have to sometimes copy all the data from one schema into another. I automated this by simple `truncate` / `insert into select *` script, but sooner realized that this way is not tolerant to changes in the source schema (adding/deleteing tables required modifying the script). So today I decided to change it to PL/PGSQL script which creates tables and copies data using dynamic queries. My first implementation was something like this:

```
do
$$
declare
  source_schema text := 'source_schema';
  dest_schema text := 'dest_schema';
  obj_name text;
  source_table text;
  dest_table text;
  alter_columns text;
begin
    for dest_table in
        select table_schema || '.' || table_name
        from information_schema.tables
        where table_schema = dest_schema
        order by table_name
    loop
        execute 'drop table ' || dest_table;
    end loop;
    raise notice 'Data cleared';

    for obj_name in
        select table_name
        from information_schema.tables
        where table_schema = source_schema
        order by table_name
    loop
        source_table := source_schema || '.' || obj_name;
        dest_table := dest_schema || '.' || obj_name;
        execute 'create unlogged table ' || dest_table
            || ' (like ' || source_table || ' including comments)';

        alter_columns := (
            select string_agg('alter column ' || column_name || ' drop not null', ', ')
            from information_schema.columns
            where table_schema = dest_schema and table_name = obj_name
                and is_nullable = 'NO');
        if alter_columns is not null then
            execute 'alter table ' || dest_table || ' ' || alter_columns;
        end if;

        execute 'insert into ' || dest_table || '  select * from ' || source_table;
        raise notice '% done', obj_name;
    end loop;    
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

As destination schema is read only, I create it without constrants to reach maximum performance. I don't think that NOT NULL constraints is a big deal, but I decided to leave everything here as it was.

This solution worked perfectly but I noticed that it was taking longer time to copy data in comparison to static script. Not dramatically, but steadily it took 20-30 seconds longer than static script.

I decided to investigate it. My first step was to comment `insert into select *` statement to find out what time takes everything else. It shown that it takes only half a second to clear and recreate all tables. My clue was that INSERT statements somehow work longer in procedureal context.

Then I added measuring of the execution time:

```
ts := clock_timestamp();
execute 'insert into ...';
raise notice 'obj_name: %', clock_timestamp() - ts;
```

Also I performed the old static script with `\timing` in psql. But this shown that my assumption was wrong. All insert statements took more or less the same time, predominantly even **faster** in dynamic script (I suppose it was due to autocommit and network roundtrips after each statement in psql). However the overal time of dynamic script was again **longer** than time of static script.

Mysticism?

Then I added very verbose logging with timestamps like this:

```
raise notice '%: %', clock_timestamp()::timestamp(3), 'label';
```

I discovered that sometimes `create table` executes immediately, but sometimes it takes several seconds to finish. OK, but how come all these statements for all tables took just milliseconds to complete in my first experiment?

Then I basically split one loop into two: first one creates all the tables (and we now know it takes just milliseconds) and the second one only inserts data:

```
do
$$
declare
  source_schema text := 'onto_oper';
  dest_schema text := 'onto';
  obj_name text;
  source_table text;
  dest_table text;
  alter_columns text;
begin
    raise notice 'Clearing data...';    
    for dest_table in
        select table_schema || '.' || table_name
        from information_schema.tables
        where table_schema = dest_schema
        order by table_name
    loop
        execute 'drop table ' || dest_table;
    end loop;
    raise notice 'Data cleared';

    for obj_name in
        select table_name
        from information_schema.tables
        where table_schema = source_schema
        order by table_name
    loop
        source_table := source_schema || '.' || obj_name;
        dest_table := dest_schema || '.' || obj_name;
        execute 'create unlogged table ' || dest_table
            || ' (like ' || source_table || ' including comments)';

        alter_columns := (
            select string_agg('alter column ' || column_name || ' drop not null', ', ')
            from information_schema.columns
            where table_schema = dest_schema and table_name = obj_name
                and is_nullable = 'NO');
        if alter_columns is not null then
            execute 'alter table ' || dest_table || ' ' || alter_columns;
        end if;
    end loop;
    raise notice 'All tables created';

    for obj_name in
        select table_name
        from information_schema.tables
        where table_schema = source_schema
        order by table_name
    loop
        source_table := source_schema || '.' || obj_name;
        dest_table := dest_schema || '.' || obj_name;
        execute 'insert into ' || dest_table || '  select * from ' || source_table;
        raise notice '% done', obj_name;
    end loop;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Surprisingly it fixed everything! This version works faster than the old static script!

We are coming to very weird conclusion: `create table` after `insert`s sometime may take long time. This is very frustrating. Despite the fact I solved my problem I don't understand why it happens. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Minor nitpick:: use `quote_ident()`,or even`format()`  for constructing dynamic queries. They will deal with crippelled table names (with spaces, CAPS,etc). And the issue is most probably caused bylocking+unlocking the catalogs during the DDL.

Comment: @wildplasser how does it explain the difference between two scripts? Why the probability to encounter the catalog lock is higher in the first case?